# Cleaner way to one-by-one construct a row and add it to a final dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have large Excel files, which contain observations of objects. I read the files via pandas, group them and then iterate over each group. For each group I calculate specific and quite complex results - let's say result1,  result2 and optional result3. 
I define an empty df with predefined columns, in which I insert my calculated values. In the end I combine all dfs to one final df.
Maybe better explained by code:

```py
data = pd.read_excel()
grouped = data.groupby('obj_id')

columns = ['result1','result2','result3']

combined_results = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for obj_id, obj_df in grouped:
    obj_results = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns,index=[0])
    # creates empty df with one all NaN row

    obj_results['result1'] = fooCalculation(obj_df)
    obj_results['result2'] = fooCalculation(obj_df)

    combined_results = combined_results.append(obj_results, sort=False)
```

I like my current method, because if optional columns end up having no value, the col still exists, because it was set (to NaN) initially. This way I can one by one calculate my result values per object and update my df row as soon as I have updates.

I can't help but think, that this is not the cleanest way. Especially because obj_results['result1'] = fooCalculation() sets an entire column and I falsely use it to set one value.

What is the clean / best-pratice way here.
Should I instead "cache" the results in a dict and insert it into the combine_results?